# Better way to write a SQL query with many ORs

Tags: mysql, sql, coding-style

I've a list or category of colors.

```
Category: Red, Blue, Green, ... //At least 9 for one category
```

And my MySQL table has entries like:

```
id  |  color
--  |  -----
 1  |  Red
 2  |  Black
 3  |  Green
 4  |  Purple
 .      .
 .      .
```

I want to get `id`s which have `color` from my category. They way I'm structuring my query right now is `... WHERE color = 'Red' OR color = 'Blue' OR ...` which would lead of a long (at least 9) list of `OR`s.

I think I'm missing something. There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in). From the documentation:

> `expr IN (value,...)`
>
> Returns 1 if expr is equal to any of the values in the IN list, else returns 0.

Your query can be changed to this:

```
WHERE color IN ('Red', 'Blue', ... )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the keyword

```
IN
```

e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   myTable
WHERE  color IN ('Red', 'Blue')
```